# How to Gitlab badges

Tags: gitlab, badge

I'm trying to add badges with gitlab and I don't understand how it works.

How can I add an "issues" badge ?

I've tried this but cannot get issues number...

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/dynamic/json.svg?label=isssues&url=[url_to_repo_issues]&query=issues&colorB=brightgreen
```

Searching the web was really not helping.
Is anyone have a good gist or something about this?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605421/how-to-create-repository-badges-in-gitlab

Comment: @nicolasPepinster Already looked at it but no valuable answer in there. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With gitlab some badges require a personal access token and using a shell script during CI build process to update an endpoint that than the shields.io dynamic badge system uses in the URL of the badge.

An easier solution is to use some pre-generated ones from badgen as badgen keeps track of those badges that gitlab will not require a personal access token o  their API to access